# JSON object post volley request can't send , shows volley failure message

Tags: android, kotlin

I can send JSON object request to post data on the server using volley but can't work properly. It always shows a volley failure error. I tried it many times but. I can't know why it happens Kindly share with me the preferable answer Kindly.

```
 private fun login() {

            val params = JSONObject()
            params.put("email",login_email.text.toString())
            params.put("password",login_password.text.toString())


            val url = "http://192.168.10.100/fitness_app/api/v1/login"


            val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)

            val request = object : JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.POST,url,params,
                Response.Listener<JSONObject> { response ->

                    val code = response.getInt("code")
                    if(code==101)

                    {
                        Toast.makeText(this,"Successfully login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }

                    else if(code==102)

                    {
                        Toast.makeText(this,"Unauthorized user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }

                    else if(code==103)

                    {
                        Toast.makeText(this,"Email does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }

                }, Response.ErrorListener {
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Something went wrong. Please try later.Volley Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            )
            {

            }
            queue.add(request)
        }
```

Comment: post error logs

Comment: I can't understand what you say because I'm a beginner level developer. Kindly if it possible u can share the exact code changing what I can do in this code for successfully tuning

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi. I can't understand what you say because I'm a beginner level developer. Kindly if it possible u can share the exact code changing what I can do in this code for successfully tuning

Comment: post response or logs you are getting  in response.

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi can you Kindly send me the code

Comment: https://github.com/AtifAbbAsi19/Login-Tutorial-Mysql-Php-Volley check out this link

Comment: I can't handle this problem

Comment: you have to try yourself first

Comment: bottom of your android studio "LogCat" is available, while running your code what kind of error or response was displayed, kindly post here

Comment: errorCode = 3
2019-11-19 15:44:15.215 704-1895/? E/CamX: [ERROR][CORE   ] camxsession.cpp:3376 InjectResult() Result holder NULL for seqId: 6, this request may be flushed out already.
2019-11-19 15:44:15.219 839-32047/? E/CameraDeviceClient: Disconnect from CameraDeviceClient

Comment: @MurugananthamS.  I can paste the logcat error in the comment above Kindly share me solution if you understand what the main issue is .....Kindly

Comment: kindly post your logcat response in your question part not in comment box, then only other developers can saw this,

Comment: the only problem is I can't make http traffic in manifest true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code given above is exactly write . I just forget to make httptrafficlibrary true in manifest that is false by default.